# fill_parent vs wrap_content listview

Tags: android, layout

I have a Layout which is as follows

---

### |Button1 | Text1 |

---

### ListView

---

### |Button2 | Text2 |

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
        <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/s1ListView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </ListView>
       </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the listview goes on top of button2 and Text2 and hides the button2 and text2. Ideally the ListView should be above the button2. What happens that if contents are more in list view then the listview hides the button2.
Should I change anything in the layout ?

Please help

Comment: Where should the listview go?

Comment: Yeah its on the top of button2 and textview2. What you actually need?

Comment: Also, you describe 2 textviews but your XML has only one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out: I have made necessary modifications

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/s1ListView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:weightSum` and `android:layout_weight` to set layout i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:weightSum="1">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
        <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
                    android:layout_weight="0.6">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/s1ListView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </ListView>
       </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2">
        <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_weight` to assign weights to each of your linear layouts and set height as 0 dp for them.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
                android:layout_weight="0.6">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/s1ListView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </ListView>
   </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2">
    <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the different between this and android:layout_weight="1" ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_weight="1"` to the LinearLayout enclosing the `listview`

```
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/s1ListView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ListView>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware of using `layout_weight` to achieve this type of layouts. As `layout_weight` is more of a work-around than solution for this requirement. You'll see the effect once you run your code which has `layout_weight` that it'll give more/less space to your top and bottom layouts than what is actually required.

Using `RelativeLayout` is **much** better option. You can use below xml to achieve the layout you need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
        <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"       
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_below="top_layout"
            android:layout_above="bottom_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/s1ListView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: which one uses  more system resources? RelativeLayout or Linear?

Comment: The key with respect to resource consumption and performance is having as minimal nested layouts as possible. In practice, a single `LinearLayout` is more efficient as far as rendering is concerned compared to a single `RelativeLayout` but then using a single `RelativeLayout` might be a better idea instead of having nested `LinearLayouts` to achieve a complex layout.